# Wine installation error in Elementary OS

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, elementary-os

I'm new on Linux and I'm using Elementary OS Hela, after trying to install Wine, when i did apt update I got this error and i can't install wine!

dpkg --print-architecture: arm64

dpkg --print-foreign-architectures: i386

Help!!!!

```
OK:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
OK:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
OK:3 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                
OK:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                          
OK:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                  
OK:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
OK:7 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
OK:8 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                
OK:9 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease                     
OK:10 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x xenial InRelease                         
OK:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic InRelease
OK:12 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic InRelease               
Ign:13 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages
Ign:14 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:15 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:16 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:13 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages
Ign:14 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:15 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:16 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:13 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages
Ign:14 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:15 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:16 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse arm64 Packages
Fehl:13 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.62.23 80]
Ign:14 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:15 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:16 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:17 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:18 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:19 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:20 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:17 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:18 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:19 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:20 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:17 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:18 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:19 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:20 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Fehl:17 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.62.23 80]
Ign:18 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:19 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:20 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:21 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/main arm64 Packages
Ign:22 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:21 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/main arm64 Packages
Ign:22 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:21 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/main arm64 Packages
Ign:22 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Fehl:21 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.62.23 80]
Ign:22 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-1386/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease« die Architektur »1386« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-arm6/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease« die Architektur »arm6« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »non-free/binary-arm6/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease« die Architektur »arm6« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »non-free/binary-arm64/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease« die Architektur »arm64« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »non-free/binary-1386/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease« die Architektur »1386« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-arm6/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease« die Architektur »arm6« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-1386/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease« die Architektur »1386« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »restricted/binary-arm6/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease« die Architektur »arm6« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »restricted/binary-1386/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease« die Architektur »1386« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »universe/binary-arm6/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease« die Architektur »arm6« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »universe/binary-1386/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease« die Architektur »1386« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »multiverse/binary-1386/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease« die Architektur »1386« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »multiverse/binary-arm6/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease« die Architektur »arm6« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-1386/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease« die Architektur »1386« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-arm6/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease« die Architektur »arm6« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »restricted/binary-1386/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease« die Architektur »1386« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »restricted/binary-arm6/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease« die Architektur »arm6« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »universe/binary-1386/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease« die Architektur »1386« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »universe/binary-arm6/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease« die Architektur »arm6« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »multiverse/binary-1386/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease« die Architektur »1386« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »multiverse/binary-arm6/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease« die Architektur »arm6« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-1386/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic InRelease« die Architektur »1386« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-arm6/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic InRelease« die Architektur »arm6« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-arm6/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease« die Architektur »arm6« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-1386/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease« die Architektur »1386« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-arm64/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease« die Architektur »arm64« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-arm6/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease« die Architektur »arm6« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-1386/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease« die Architektur »1386« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »restricted/binary-1386/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease« die Architektur »1386« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »restricted/binary-arm6/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease« die Architektur »arm6« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »universe/binary-1386/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease« die Architektur »1386« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »universe/binary-arm6/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease« die Architektur »arm6« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »multiverse/binary-arm6/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease« die Architektur »arm6« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »multiverse/binary-1386/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease« die Architektur »1386« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-arm6/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease« die Architektur »arm6« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-arm64/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease« die Architektur »arm64« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-1386/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease« die Architektur »1386« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-1386/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic InRelease« die Architektur »1386« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-arm6/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic InRelease« die Architektur »arm6« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-1386/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic InRelease« die Architektur »1386« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-arm64/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic InRelease« die Architektur »arm64« nicht unterstützt.
N: Das Laden der konfigurierten Datei »main/binary-arm6/Packages« wird übersprungen, da das Depot »http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic InRelease« die Architektur »arm6« nicht unterstützt.
E: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-arm64/Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.62.23 80]
E: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.62.23 80]
E: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.62.23 80]
E: Einige Indexdateien konnten nicht heruntergeladen werden. Sie wurden ignoriert oder alte an ihrer Stelle benutzt.
```

Comment: Your architectures are messed up, note the `1386` (misspelled `i386`) and the lines containing `arm64` and `arm6`. Please [edit] the question and add the output of `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`.

Comment: dpkg --print-architecture: arm64,  dpkg --print-foreign-architectures: i386

Comment: Crossposted on askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315500/wine-installation-error-on-e-os

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you messed up some console commands when you tried to add architectures previously. `1386` and `arm6` do not actually exist – they are typos. You should be able to remove them from your configuration via

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture 1386
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture arm6
```

Also, `arm64` and `i386` are completely different architectures which usually cannot effectively be mixed. Please read the text carefully when following guides. Don't just randomly type commands into the console. That would be a recipe for pain and suffering.

I advise you to remove all files for foreign package sources from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Then you clean `/etc/apt/sources.list` so it only contains the necessary defaults:

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Now you can start over with a clean apt package manager configuration.